# Access all children elements of included layouts from main layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-include

I have a `activity_main` layout which looks like the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    android:layout_gravity = "bottom"
    android:gravity = "bottom">
    <include
        android:id = "@+id/call_to_action"
        layout = "@layout/call_to_action_layout"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>
    <include
        android:id = "@+id/status"
        layout = "@layout/status_layout"
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Both of my included layouts look like these:

Here's the `call_to_action_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/action_button_container"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the `status_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/another_container"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In `MainActivity.java` I am trying to set a property of all `EditText` that are present in my `activity_main.xml`. For that, I need to loop over and access every `EditText` present in my layout.

So here's what I've tried so far in `MainActivity.java`

```
RelativeLayout container = findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "id: " + container.getChildAt(i));

    if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) {
        EditText editText =
            (EditText) container.getChildAt(i);
        editText.setKeyListener(null);
    }
}
```

But because of `<include>` tag, I am not able to access all of the `EditText` in this code.

Is there any way to do this?

Note: Basically, all want to do is disable all the `EditText` present in my layout.

Comment: But because of <include> tag, I am not able to access all of the EditText in this code. - I didn't quite really understand that. You should be able to `findViewById` in the included layouts from your `MainActivity.java`. Did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you're only iterating through first level children of your layout (`call_to_action` and `status`).

You can either do two loops like this:

```
ViewGroup call_to_action = findViewById(R.id.call_to_action)
for (int i = 0; i < call_to_action.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "id: " + call_to_action.getChildAt(i));
    if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText)
    {
        EditText editText =
            (EditText) call_to_action.getChildAt(i);
        editText.setKeyListener(null);
    }
}

ViewGroup status = findViewById(R.id.status)
for (int i = 0; i < status.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "id: " + status.getChildAt(i));
    if (status .getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText)
    {
        EditText editText =
            (EditText) status.getChildAt(i);
        editText.setKeyListener(null);
    }
}
```

Or create a recursive method like this one:

```
public void removeKeyListeners(ViewGroup container){
for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "id: " + container.getChildAt(i));
        if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText)
        {
            EditText editText =
                (EditText) container.getChildAt(i);
            editText.setKeyListener(null);
        } else if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
              removeKeyListeners((ViewGroup) container.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

and call it for your layout:

```
removeKeyListeners(container);
```

Note: using `ViewGroup` here because all `Layouts` are subclasses of it.